# Boot process enters an infinite loop after installing Ubuntu 11.04 together with Windows 7 and XP

Tags: boot-failure, multiboot

I have a new computer ACER Aspire X3960 which came with Windows 7 preinstalled. I made a new partition where I installed Windows XP and then I installed in new logical partitions (a Swap, a / and a /home partition) Ubuntu 11.04.

At the end of the process, the computer enters the very first screen where it says "press DEL to enter BIOS setup, press F12 to enter BOOT options".

After a few seconds, the screen goes blank, the computer beeps and then it presents the same screen again.

It doesn't even ever go to the grub options of which operating system I want to start. It just loops there forever.

I tried to fix the (eventually damaged) grub following these instructions (unfortunately in german) http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur from a LiveUSB, which I'm also using to post this question.

Now I found here that someone asked for the results of the Boot Info Script. Here is mine (I hope I did right in trying to upload the file):

http://paste.ubuntu.com/736032/

Can anybody help? Thank you very much.

Andreafc

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to AskUbuntu.

Your Ubuntu installation is on /dev/sda6. Please use the following commands to reinstall GRUB correctly from the CD:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Windows 7 installation disc. If you don't have one, use the manufacturer' s recovery disc(s). Select your language , keyboard layout, and country, and press next. Click recovery options in the lower left-hand corner of the window. Click command prompt. Run the commands **fixboot** and **fixmbr**. When they are finished, eject the disc and restart the computer. This will restart the computer to it's default bootloader.